# Enable downloads and disable IE ESC on Windows Server 2008 (and R2)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer

How can I enable downloads for Windows Server 2008? By default when I try to download something with internet explorer the download is blocked.

Comment: This is quite ambiguous. We need more info please

Answer (score 19):

Go to Server Manager > Configure IE ESC (under Security Information) and disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Configuration for administrators.

Alternatively (and probably safer) is to either download from a workstation and save it to a share on the server or add the site in question to the trusted sites temporarily/permanently, depending on how often you'll be returning.

I generally proxy Web surfing on my servers with a set whitelist for various updates (like WSUS, Java, or whatever else is required).

[image]

Comment: +1 for the response. Especially downloading to a workstation and moving via a share - keep browsing off the server if possible.

Comment: Pretty picture courtesy of Chris S.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable this from internet option.

Follow these steps:

1. Open IE or go to C Panel.
2. On IE under "Tools" you will find Internet options.
3. Or you can open Internet options from CPanel.
4. Now select "Security" from top and go to Custom Settings.
5. Scroll down a bit and enable download options.

Enjoy. But the best recommendation is to keep download disabled at least for your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in using SCCM's Configuration Baselines (or just regular old Group Policy) to check for compliance and/or force remediation of IE ESC here are relevant Registry Keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}

Value Name: IsInstalled
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 00000001 (Enabled)
```

You want to set your Configuration Item to ensure that the value of `IsInstalled` is `00000001` for the feature to be enabled or conversely `00000000` to disable it. The first key (`A509B1A7...`) controls IE ESC for Administrators and the second key (`A509B1A8...`) for regular users.